# What is the best way to design, generate, and version a database schema script for MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have never really seen any questions (with answers) as general as this, so I'm hoping to get some useful feedback. The reason I'm asking is because I've done all of this before and I have my own ways, but sometimes I feel it's not the best practice.

Let's take for example that I can't afford better db modeling tools and I only have sql server and ms sql server management studio. What I do is:

- I design with mssms, all of the entities in my db (tables, primary keys, foreign keys, indexes, etc)
- then I just generate the schema script using 'Generate Scripts...' command in mssms. The script that's generated is rather large (using sql server express 2012) and seems like it's not organized for maintenance very well.
  **Example**: after all the table creation scripts are setup, there's a bunch of `ALTER TABLE` commands to add all the constraints. This kind of thing seems like it would be better in the table creation script section, maybe not. Also, for upgrade-ability, I normally add for each table creation section, '`IF NOT EXISTS`', so that it doesn't throw an error when I need to re-run the sql script when the db is updated with new tables, columns, etc.
- Then for versioning, I generally have a separate script that I run to add the schema version in a VERSION table in the db itself (with just one row).
  This allows me to do incremental upgrades when I run the script by adding 'if new-version > current-version' sort of thing.

It seems to have worked out for me in the past, but it just seems kind of, I don't know, not very sophisticated. Can a sql expert shed some light on this subject? It's something we all do for every data driven web app we create, over and over again. I'd like to see how other developers do it.

**To recap**,

1. how do you go about designing your db model and generate scripts (do you do it with a design tool, write from scratch, etc?),
2. how to you manage incremental db changes over time?
3. How do you version control your database?

Comment: Redgate SQL Compare is a pretty good tool for generating scripts from the database (which can be stored in source control) You can then add to/alter these scripts and it will generate a release and rollback script for you that can be used to apply changes to a staging or live database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Data Tools is ideal for this. It has all the design features you require and configurable scripting. It will also diff two databases and generate the change script for you. Oh - and it's free!

Comment: I've been using SSDT for a while now and for incremental changes and schema versioning this is probably the best and most solid solution. You just have to make sure all the devs that make changes to the database are disciplined enough to always make their changes via SSDT.